# One-shot DHCP request with systemd-networkd

Tags: linux-networking, dhclient, systemd-networkd

How to/is it possible to make a one-shot DHCP request without writing/modifying a `.network` file for the interface?

With `dhclient`, you could just run `dhclient enp23s0f4` to obtain an IP address. I am looking for an equivalent, preferably using only `ip` and `systemd-networkd`-associated tools.

For more context, assume there is an interface on a server that is physically connected to an upstream network, but is otherwise left unconfigured or down; in particular it has no `.network` unit associated.

In regular working conditions the interface should stay this way, but occasionally an admin needs to bring the interface up and configure it with DHCP. Previously they would `ip link set enp23s0f4 up` and then `dhclient enp23s0f4` to obtain an address, but `isc-dhcp-client` [has been deprecated](https://www.isc.org/dhcp/). `networkctl` can be used to bring the interface up and managed by `systemd-networkd`, e.g. `networkctl up enp23s0f4`:

```
# networkctl status enp23s0f4
● 2: enp23s0f4
                   Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                Network File: n/a
                       State: degraded (unmanaged)
                Online state: unknown
                        Type: ether
                        Path: pci-0000:17:00.4
...
```

Obviously, the admin may create a simple network unit file and configure the device this way, e.g.:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/enp23s0f4.network
[Match]
Name=enp23s0f4
[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

And then use `networkctl reload` to apply the configuration, but this has the potential dangers of leaving the configuration file. I am specifically **not** asking for this solution and looking for something ephemeral that won't survive random restart. The closest I can think of is putting the unit file in `/run/systemd/network` instead of `/etc`, but this still seems like an unnecessary workaround rather than a proper solution.